# Drupal 7 to 8 migration The "taxonomy_term_reference_plain" plugin does not exist

Tags: 8, migrations

When running the d7_field_formatter_settings.yml (in core/modules/field/migrations/) migration I get the following error.

```
The "taxonomy_term_reference_plain" plugin does not exist
```

Has the taxonomy_term_reference_plain formatter been removed from Drupal 8?
If so what is the equivalent in drupal 8 and how can I map taxonomy_term_reference_plain into its drupal 8 equivalent during migration

Answer (score 0):

Yes, taxonomy terms are now treated as general entities rather than special (for the most part), so some of the taxonomy-specific formatters were inevitably removed.

I believe the `entity_reference_label` formatter is the natural replacement for Drupal 8.